# d3 drag when elements are on top of each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When multiple elements that share coordinates have drag beauvoir assigned to them, the "dragstart" event is invoked for all elments under the mouse but the "drag" and "dragend" are only invoked for one of them.

check out the console output on this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AsherBarak/np7g10be/

Is this by design? What if I need to have different drag behvioure for different elements that happened to be stacked?

```
var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function () {
    console.log('Start Dragging Group');
})
    .on('drag', function (d, i) {
    console.log('Dragging Group');
})
    .on('dragend', function (d, i) {
    console.log('Ended Dragging Group');
});

var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function () {
    console.log('Start Dragging Circle');
})
    .on('drag', function (d, i) {
    console.log('Dragging Circle');
})
    .on('dragend', function (d, i) {
    console.log('Ended Dragging circle');
});

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('viewBox', '-50 -50 300 300');
var g = svg.selectAll('g').data([{
    x: 10,
    y: 10
}])
    .enter().append('g').call(dragGroup);

g.append('rect').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100);

g.selectAll('circle').data([{
    cx: 90,
    cy: 80
}]).enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
    return d.cx
})
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
    return d.cy
})
    .attr('r', 30)
.call(dragCircle);
```

Comment: the circle is within the group on which you are attaching the drag listener(dragGroup).
For different element you can attach different listeners. Like in your case attach _dragGroup_ to rect and _dragCircle_ then it will work teh way you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping sourceEvent propagation on `dragstart` event of circle will fix this issue.

> `stopPropagation` method prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
>   tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function() {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Start Dragging Circle');
    })
    .on('drag', function(d, i) {
        console.log('Dragging Circle');
    });
```

```js
var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function() {
        console.log('Start Dragging Group');
    })
    .on('drag', function(d, i) {
        console.log('Dragging Group');
    });

var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function() {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Start Dragging Circle');
    })
    .on('drag', function(d, i) {
console.log('Dragging Circle');
    });

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('viewBox', '-50 -50 300 300');
var g = svg.selectAll('g').data([{x:10,y:10}])
    .enter().append('g').call(dragGroup);

g.append('rect').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100);

g.selectAll('circle').data([{cx: 90,cy:80}]).enter()
    .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d){ return d.cx })
        .attr('cy', function(d){ return d.cy })
        .attr('r', 30)
        .call(dragCircle);
```

```css
circle{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```